# Deployment slot is redirecting to same root domain

Tags: deployment, dns, root, slot

My frontend and backend applications are web APIs. I have created a App services for both and published code in Microsoft Azure. I don't have any issues with regular App services. Now, I wanted to deploy code in separate slot with my latest changes so that if my functionality works as expected, I can simply swap it. So, I have created a new slot and published my code. When I tried login to the slot url, it is redirecting me to error.html page in root domain.

I checked in kudu services, redirect URI is pointing to slot url only. 
I have added slot url in App registrations of Active directory.
Also, web.config settings of my front end application is below and I think it doesnt need any changes to fix this issue.

```
     <rules>
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I tried all ways to fix the issue but not worked. Can anyone help me in fixing the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by migrating the code to GIT since deployment slots are supported in Azure devops only if code is pushed to GIT. TFS is not supported in Azure DevOps.